# Installing Windows 11 on Gigabyte Aorus Elite B550M

Tags: motherboard, windows-11, windows-installation, clean-install

For the 1st time in decades; I'm struggling to install Windows on my Computer.
I've recently moved to a new Motherboard (Gigabyte Aorus Elite B550M).
I need to perform a Windows 11 Clean Install from USB Pen Drive.
Windows 11 currently is running on this current Setup and the Hardware is completely compatible for Windows 11.
On the BIOS: TPM and Secure Bot is Enabled, but Windows Setup will always fail informing that the Computer does not meet the requirements; (but it does).

Any thoughts regading this subject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if there's Firmware (UEFI/BIOS) update available for the Motherboard and update the same and retry. What is the source of Windows 11 ISO file from which  you eventually created USB installer?

Comment: @patkim: Thanks for the prompt reply. BIOS is up to date. Regarding the source: I'm not sure I understood what you meant. The Source is from Microsoft Media Creator (wich downloads and creates the Bootable Instalation and Sets it to the USB Drive.

Comment: @Ricardo - Use Rufus instead and enable the feature to install Windows 11 on incompatible hardware.

Comment: Run [WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) to find if the hardware is truly compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It has been over a decade since I worked as IT Technician and there are lots of features in BIOS that are new to me nowadays.
I’m feeling outdated…

I Ended up with persistence on trial and error.
I deleted Cleared the BIOS, TPM and TPM Key around 10 times; then finally Windows Setup finally ran.
The procedures were almost the same every time, with a few other options toggled in each step (testing things I did not know).
Analysing my procedures I’m sure the current F15 BIOS version is bugged.

Aside from this thread subject:
After installing the OS; I could ensure that this board has some sort of “lag”; maybe CPU and/or GPU throttling.
Replaced the Motherboard to the previous; and got my performance back.

Im returning the motherboard. it was an upgrade that decreased performance drastically.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The motherboard wasn't the issue, but the boot order was.

Make sure when selecting the boot order on your USB creation drive, you select the UEFI partition, not the other partition.